# Why in native query Hibernate lazy load's children entities?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I don't understand it, when I use JPQL with JOIN fetch hibernate should do one query to join children entities, but when I want to use native query and join all children with one query hibernate still lazy loads children in other queries. 
I'm using Spring Data 2.

What should I do to avoid **Lazy loading** or **n+1** queries with using **native query**?

Example:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT recipe.*, r_ing.*, ing.* FROM recipe recipe join " +
        " on recipe.id = r.recipe_id " +
        " LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients r_ing on r.recipe_id = r_ing.recipe_id " +
        " LEFT JOIN ingredient ing on r_ing.ingredient_id = ing.id where ing.names in (:ingredientsNames)",
        countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM recipe recipe join " +
                " on recipe.id = r.recipe_id " +
                " LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients r_ing on r.recipe_id = r_ing.recipe_id " +
                " LEFT JOIN ingredient ing on r_ing.ingredient_id = ing.id where ing.names in (:ingredientsNames)",
        nativeQuery = true
)
Page<Recipe> findAllByIngredientsNames(List<String> ingredientsNames, Pageable page);
```

Entieties:

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<RecipeIngredients> ingredients;
}
@Entity
public class RecipeIngredients implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RecipeIngredientsId recipeIngredientsId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("recipeId")
    private Recipe recipe;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @MapsId("ingredientId")
        private Ingredient ingredient;
}

@Entity
public class Ingredient {

    @NaturalId
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Please add your controller/service code and if your using any dto for response then add it also. Also, try to minimal code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a native query, Hibernate does not know how to map advanced data. In your case, you have a request to fetch the `Recipe` entity, where the entity mapper knows how to extract results from `SELECT * FROM recipe`. But `ingredients` property is the reverse mapping, which is implemented as a lazy init collection, with query behind. That what JPA and Spring data made for you, but they are not smart enough to *automagically* understand and map it further to eagerly map the query results to a collection property.

Also, I guess you have seen in the results of your query multiple same `Recipe` entities.

If for whatever reason you really want to deal with native queries, so just use those properly: results of the native query are in general not a JPA managed *entities*, but rather projections.

So create a specific projection of the row you are having in your native query:

```
public class FullRecipeProjection {
    private final Integer recipeId; 
    private final Integer recipeIngredientsId;
    private final Integer ingredientId
    private final Integer ingredientName 

    /* Full-arg-constructor */
    public FullRecipeProjection (Integer recipeId, Integer recipeIngredientsId, Integer ingredientId, String ingredientName) {...}

}
```

Then you can create your query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new FullRecipeProjection(recipe.recipeId, r_ing.recipeIngredientsId, ing.ingredientId, ing.IngredientName) FROM recipe recipe join " +
        " on recipe.id = r.recipe_id " +
        " LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients r_ing on r.recipe_id = r_ing.recipe_id " +
        " LEFT JOIN ingredient ing on r_ing.ingredient_id = ing.id where ing.names in (:ingredientsNames)",
        countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM recipe recipe join " +
                " on recipe.id = r.recipe_id " +
                " LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients r_ing on r.recipe_id = r_ing.recipe_id " +
                " LEFT JOIN ingredient ing on r_ing.ingredient_id = ing.id where ing.names in (:ingredientsNames)",
        nativeQuery = true
)
List<FullRecipeProjection> findAllByIngredientsNames(List<String> ingredientsNames);
```

Then you can transform the collection of `FullRecipeProjection` to a similar object of your `Recipe`:

```
public class FullRecipe {
    private final Integer recipeId;
    private final Set<IngredientProjection> ingredients;
    public FullRecipe(Integer recipeId, Set<IngredientProjection> ingredients) {...}
}

public class IngredientProjection {
    private final Integer ingredientId;
    private final String ingredientName;
    public IngredientProjection(Integer ingredientId, String ingredientName) {...}
}
```

And then you can get what you want like this:

```
final List<FullRecipeProjection> data = repository.findAllByIngredientsNames(ingredientsNames);

final List<FullRecipe> results = data
    .stream()
    // extracting distinct identities of recipes, you have fetched  
    .map(FullRecipeProjection::recipeId)
    .distinct()
    // now we have unique key for the data and can map it
    .map(it -> 
         new FullRecipe(
             it, 
             // extracting all ingredients, which  were fetched in rows with references to recipe.
             data
                 .stream()
                 .filter(o -> o.recipeId.equals(it))
                 .map(ing -> new IngredientProjection(ing.ingredientId, ing.ingredientName))
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet())
    .collect(Collectors.toList()) ;
```

Quite a long way. But that is how it works.  And when you use JPQL queries this long processing is done by Hibernate.

And note: pagination becomes a cumbersome operation for this kind of data extraction: In a way you have specified, you will paginate not the final result, but the `FullRecipeProjection`, which may result in a not-complete `Recipe` fetch, and for sure in badly paged data (it may contain only 1 `FullRecipe`, which in place could be not fully loaded!).